# RSpec2 & Rails3, issue with the basics of testing helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, rspec2

That's certainly trivial but can't figure out what goes wrong.

**Helper : app/helpers/bookings_helper.rb**

```
module BookingsHelper
  def booking_price(booking)
    "something"
  end
end
```

**Helper spec : spec/helpers/bookings_helper_spec.rb**

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper')

describe BookingsHelper do
  describe "#booking_price" do
    helper.booking_price.should == 'something'
  end
end
```

**Error**

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing': undefined method `booking_price' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using it instead of describe for the inside block:

```
describe BookingsHelper do
  it "#booking_price" do
    helper.booking_price.should == 'something'
  end
end
```

Comment: As I said, it's trivial and the obvious. Funny how we can't skip such things sometimes. Thanks for your help, much apprciated